# `chalk` library does not print colored text after bundle using webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, chalk

I use `chalk` to write a simple script, and bundle the code using `webpack`.
The code print colored text before bundle, but print text **without** color after bundle
using webpack.

The test code is:

```js
const chalk = require('chalk')

function main() {
  console.log(chalk.blue('chalk'))
}

main()
```

The `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main.js'),
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
 
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
  },
}
```

What happened ?

Answer (score 1):

For me was in the webpack configuration, I was compiling for web target instead of node target =]

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with your individual computer or terminal. I had a similar situation, where a simple use of `chalk` wasn't working. Once I stopped using Solarized themes in my terminal preferences, `chalk` worked as expected.

(In my searching for solutions, there were a few other solutions out there for weird behavior, solved by such things as uninstalling iTerm2.)